# How to read a txt file in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a text file speedVan.txt in my assets folder in android studio which stores coordinates, However when I run it the markers do not appear on the map. My code is below, thank you.

This is the content of the text file, there are no spaces between the text lines:

```
52.2651 -9.7112 52.2791 -9.7024

52.2800 -9.7675 52.2746 -9.8096

52.1407 -10.1748 52.1296 -10.2493

52.0724 -9.5753 52.1005 -9.6231

52.1021 -9.6276 52.1065 -9.6425 

52.0812 -9.2470 52.0542 -9.3850

52.1134 -9.5169 52.1437 -9.5543

52.4096 -9.5167 52.4208 -9.5078

52.4428 -9.4105 52.4491 -9.4474
```

This is my activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("speedVan.txt")));
            String line;
            //Log.e("Reader Stuff",reader.readLine());
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("code",line);
                String[] ar1 = line.split(" ");

                double startLat = Double.parseDouble(ar1[0]);
                double startLong = Double.parseDouble(ar1[1]);
                double endLat = Double.parseDouble(ar1[2]);
                double endLong = Double.parseDouble(ar1[3]);

                LatLng start = new LatLng(startLat, startLong);
                LatLng end = new LatLng(endLat, endLong);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start).title(""));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(end).title(""));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(start,14));

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change SupportMapFragment to MapFragment. Something like this

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Comment: No this did not work, I have put in the contents of the text file also, thank you.

Comment: float startLat = Float.parseFloat(ar1[0]); is not working?

Comment: No this still does not add markers for me, but thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Are you sure mMap is not getting populated.Have you checked that.May be the issue is with displaying it.Also please add some relevant title to marker for better understanding

Comment: When you say populated do you mean populated with markers? I have implemented the markers separately and they display no problem.  What do you mean add relevant title for marker? Sorry my English is not very good.

Comment: mMap.addMarker.. after this line gets executed does mMap has data inside it.Can you please confirm that.Also what do you mean when you say "I have implemented the markers separately and they display no problem"

Comment: I mean that if I use the addMarker method and manually type in the coordinates, it works.  I just have so many and when I use the loop it does not put any.. :(

Comment: Can you please again check there should be space between all coordinate entries 52.2651 <space> -9.7112 52.2791 in the file.and single space in this split(" ");

Comment: Yes there is a single space between all of them, I have tested this in another java program and the file is fine.

Comment: Can you please change SupportMapFragment to MapFragment and try once.
Something like this MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

Comment: That worked, thank you very much for all of your help you are great :)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `;;` that you have used and put a single `;`

And instead of:

```
int startLat = Integer.parseInt(ar1[0]);
int startLong = Integer.parseInt(ar1[1]);;
int endLat = Integer.parseInt(ar1[2]);;
int endLong = Integer.parseInt(ar1[3]);;
```

Please put:

```
double startLat = Double.parseDouble(ar1[0]);
double startLong = Double.parseDouble(ar1[1]);
double endLat = Double.parseDouble(ar1[2]);
double endLong = Double.parseDouble(ar1[3]);
```

We are using double because the constructor of `LatLng` **takes two** `double` arguements.

And please note that because of your first statement `Log.e("Reader Stuff",reader.readLine());` the first line of the text file will not be parsed because a line is being read and logged and the next time you call `reader.readLine()`, you will get the second line.

**Edit:**

Maybe you are not able to see the markers because you haven't moved the map camera. To move the camera to any marker:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(start,14));
```

`start` is the `LatLng` and `14` is the Zoom level.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did not know that the first line would not be parsed.  I have tried fixing it but still no markers :(

Comment: Have you tried changing the map camera? And please update the question with any more code which you feel has errors.

Comment: Yes I have changed the camera and moved it around. I have updated to include the code, Sorry I wasnt able to format it correctly at the top and the very end, I left out just some import statements

Comment: If the code is compiling fine then there must be some kind of `IOException`. Please search in logcat for any kind of error. It will be helpful if you add a `Log.e()` statement in the catch block.